# line break in xml file

Tags: c#, .net

I am doing a CRUD of students and I am saving each of them in an XML file. The case is that when saving them, they are saved in the same line.

The code is this:

```
using(StreamWriter sr = File.AppendText(Xml))
using(XmlTextWriter xml = new XmlTextWriter(sr))
{
     xml.WriteElementString(Xml, dataStudent);
}
```

And the output looks like this:

```
<.\student.xml>b4f6d4ca-ba74-4f33-9481-a24e3efffcfa, 54, Deni, Suco, 12/6/1972</.\student.xml><.\student.xml>cf98fab5-5b13-4c4c-849c-ebbb1c7157ab, 56, Sandy, Whoknows, 12/8/79</.\student.xml>
```

And I want that:

```
<.\student.xml>b4f6d4ca-ba74-4f33-9481-a24e3efffcfa, 54, Deni, Suco, 12/6/1972</.\student.xml>
<.\student.xml>cf98fab5-5b13-4c4c-849c-ebbb1c7157ab, 56, Sandy, Whoknows, 12/8/79</.\student.xml>
```

Comment: Investigate [`XmlWriterSettings`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlwritersettings.indent?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Comment: you should first rethink your xml structure ...element `<.\student.xml>` looks awkward ... next: `b4f6d4ca-ba74-4f33-9481-a24e3efffcfa, 54, Deni, Suco, 12/6/1972` looks even mor awkward ... it shoudl be rather `<student id="b4f6d4ca-ba74-4f33-9481-a24e3efffcfa" someNumber="54" prollyName="Deni" prollySurname="Suco" someDate="12/6/1972" />` or `<student><id>b4f6d4ca-ba74-4f33-9481-a24e3efffcfa</id><someNumber>54</someNumber>....</student>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following property of XmlTextWriter.

```
xml.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
xml.Indentation = 4;
```

Here is the link
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmltextwriter.indentation?view=netframework-4.7.2